# How to downgrade hdf5 installed with tensorflow-gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, hdf5

recently i have tried to install tensorflow-gpu following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPq6NIboLSc this video

But when I try to import tensorflow (or keras) my kernal dies giving following error message.

```
C:\Users\ovin\Anaconda3\envs\GPU\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py:40: UserWarning: h5py is running against HDF5 1.10.5 when it was built against 1.10.4, this may cause problems
```

'{0}.{1}.{2}'.format(*version.hdf5_built_version_tuple)
Warning! ***HDF5 library version mismatched error***
The HDF5 header files used to compile this application do not match
the version used by the HDF5 library to which this application is linked.
Data corruption or segmentation faults may occur if the application continues.
This can happen when an application was compiled by one version of HDF5 but
linked with a different version of static or shared HDF5 library.
You should recompile the application or check your shared library related
settings such as 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'.
You can, at your own risk, disable this warning by setting the environment
variable 'HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK' to a value of '1'.
Setting it to 2 or higher will suppress the warning messages totally.
Headers are 1.10.4, library is 1.10.5
        SUMMARY OF THE HDF5 CONFIGURATION
        =================================

### General Information:

```
               HDF5 Version: 1.10.5
              Configured on: 2019-03-04
              Configured by: Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64
                Host system: Windows-10.0.17763
          Uname information: Windows
                   Byte sex: little-endian
         Installation point: C:/Program Files/HDF5
```

### Compiling Options:

```
                 Build Mode:
          Debugging Symbols:
                    Asserts:
                  Profiling:
         Optimization Level:
```

### Linking Options:

```
                  Libraries:
```

Statically Linked Executables: OFF
                        LDFLAGS: /machine:x64
                     H5_LDFLAGS:
                     AM_LDFLAGS:
                Extra libraries:
                       Archiver:
                         Ranlib:

### Languages:

```
                          C: yes
                 C Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe 19.16.27027.1
                   CPPFLAGS:
                H5_CPPFLAGS:
                AM_CPPFLAGS:
                     CFLAGS:  /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3
                  H5_CFLAGS:
                  AM_CFLAGS:
           Shared C Library: YES
           Static C Library: YES

                    Fortran: OFF
           Fortran Compiler:
              Fortran Flags:
           H5 Fortran Flags:
           AM Fortran Flags:
     Shared Fortran Library: YES
     Static Fortran Library: YES

                        C++: ON
               C++ Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe 19.16.27027.1
                  C++ Flags: /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc
               H5 C++ Flags:
               AM C++ Flags:
         Shared C++ Library: YES
         Static C++ Library: YES

                        JAVA: OFF
               JAVA Compiler:
```

### Features:

```
               Parallel HDF5: OFF
```

Parallel Filtered Dataset Writes:
              Large Parallel I/O:
              High-level library: ON
                    Threadsafety: OFF
             Default API mapping: v110
  With deprecated public symbols: ON
          I/O filters (external):  DEFLATE DECODE ENCODE
                             MPE:
                      Direct VFD:
                         dmalloc:
  Packages w/ extra debug output:
                     API Tracing: OFF
            Using memory checker: OFF
 Memory allocation sanity checks: OFF
          Function Stack Tracing: OFF
       Strict File Format Checks: OFF
    Optimization Instrumentation:
Bye...

Things already tried,

- I have selected the correct kernal
- tried to uninstall and install hdf5=1.10.4 version
- updated the conda environment

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with C Language as I am using Python. But I resolved this with installing the previous version using Anaconda.

```
conda install -c conda-forge hdf5=1.10.4
```