# tensorflow 2.3.0 requires h5py<2.11.0,>=2.10.0, but you'll have h5py 3.1.0 which is incompatible

Tags: python, pip

when I'm running

```
pip3 install face-compare
```

I got the below error, any suggestions

```
ERROR: After October 2020 you may experience errors when installing or updating packages. This is because pip will change the way that it resolves dependency conflicts.

We recommend you use --use-feature=2020-resolver to test your packages with the new resolver before it becomes the default.

tensorflow 2.3.0 requires h5py<2.11.0,>=2.10.0, but you'll have h5py 3.1.0 which is incompatible.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to downgrade hdf5 installed with tensorflow-gpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60468770/how-to-downgrade-hdf5-installed-with-tensorflow-gpu)

Answer (score 1):

```
pip uninstall h5py
pip install h5py==2.10.0
```