# Error using Tensorflow after updating Spyder 5.0.0 and Anaconda navigator

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, spyder

Hello I updated my installation of Anaconda3 and Spyder to v5.0.0 and now I'm having an error while running a simple linear regression using Tensorflow.

The error I'm getting is as follows:

2021-05-23 10:24:01.668571: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2021 10:45:00.233015: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Warning! ***HDF5 library version mismatched error***
The HDF5 header files used to compile this application do not match
the version used by the HDF5 library to which this application is linked.
Data corruption or segmentation faults may occur if the application continues.
This can happen when an application was compiled by one version of HDF5 but
linked with a different version of static or shared HDF5 library.
You should recompile the application or check your shared library related
settings such as 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'.
You can, at your own risk, disable this warning by setting the environment
variable 'HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK' to a value of '1'.
Setting it to 2 or higher will suppress the warning messages totally.
Headers are 1.10.4, library is 1.10.5
SUMMARY OF THE HDF5 CONFIGURATION
=================================

### General Information:

```
               HDF5 Version: 1.10.5
              Configured on: 2019-03-04
              Configured by: Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64
                Host system: Windows-10.0.17763
          Uname information: Windows
                   Byte sex: little-endian
         Installation point: C:/Program Files/HDF5
```

### Compiling Options:

```
                 Build Mode: 
          Debugging Symbols: 
                    Asserts: 
                  Profiling: 
         Optimization Level:
```

### Linking Options:

```
                  Libraries:
```

Statically Linked Executables: OFF
LDFLAGS: /machine:x64
H5_LDFLAGS:
AM_LDFLAGS:
Extra libraries:
Archiver:
Ranlib:

### Languages:

```
                          C: yes
                 C Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe 19.16.27027.1
                   CPPFLAGS: 
                H5_CPPFLAGS: 
                AM_CPPFLAGS: 
                     CFLAGS:  /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3
                  H5_CFLAGS: 
                  AM_CFLAGS: 
           Shared C Library: YES
           Static C Library: YES

                    Fortran: OFF
           Fortran Compiler:  
              Fortran Flags: 
           H5 Fortran Flags: 
           AM Fortran Flags: 
     Shared Fortran Library: YES
     Static Fortran Library: YES

                        C++: ON
               C++ Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe 19.16.27027.1
                  C++ Flags: /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc
               H5 C++ Flags: 
               AM C++ Flags: 
         Shared C++ Library: YES
         Static C++ Library: YES

                        JAVA: OFF
               JAVA Compiler:
```

### Features:

```
               Parallel HDF5: OFF
```

Parallel Filtered Dataset Writes:
Large Parallel I/O:
High-level library: ON
Threadsafety: OFF
Default API mapping: v110
With deprecated public symbols: ON
I/O filters (external):  DEFLATE DECODE ENCODE
MPE:
Direct VFD:
dmalloc:
Packages w/ extra debug output:
API Tracing: OFF
Using memory checker: OFF
Memory allocation sanity checks: OFF
Function Stack Tracing: OFF
Strict File Format Checks: OFF
Optimization Instrumentation:
Bye...

Things that I did:

- Updated Anaconda
- Updated Spyder from 3.3.4 to 5.0.0
- Downgraded the conda install -c conda-forge hdf5=1.10.4 as recommended in [similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60468770/how-to-downgrade-hdf5-installed-with-tensorflow-gpu)

Apparently is something related to my previously installed version of Tensorflow - it seems it's trying to use the version with GPU NVidia (CUDA) and I don't have a GPU in my computer.

How can I fix the Tensorflow library? (uninstall/reinstall?)

(sorry about this basic question)

Comment: Apparently when I added '--user' into the command "pip install --upgrade tensorflow --user" fixed the kernel crash problem, but I'm still receiving an error regarding the 'cuda' library.

Comment: The reference for the previous comment was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912999/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-winerror-5-access-is-de)

Comment: HDF5 library version mismatched error will be resolved with `pip install h5py --upgrade --no-dependencies --force`. You can ignore above `CUDA` warnings if you do not have a `GPU` set up on your machine. If you don't want to see any such error try to install `pip install tensorflow_cpu-2.5.0`. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! that "cuda" warnings are really boring! ;)